# Is there a way to drill down from rpivotTable in Shiny

Tags: shiny, rpivottable

Is there a way to make an rPivotTable reactive so if you click on a value you can get to the underlying rows?

```
 tabPanel("Pivot Table",
           shinycssloaders::withSpinner(
            rpivotTableOutput("pivot_table")
           )
  )
```

Comment: Providing us with a reproducible example would be helpful.

Comment: You want me to produce an example of a feature, which I don’t know exists?